# How to convert C# date time variable to NSDate?

Tags: c#, json, swift, wcf, nsdate

I have an iOS application that is programmed with Swift. This application gets data from a WCF service (A JSON restful service). My problem is my service send a C# date time variable to mobile application through WCF service in JSON format.

This is my date that is posted by the service:

> "From":"/Date(1454956200000+0530)/",

I want to convert this to NSDate format.

Comment: var responsedate: String = "/Date(1454956200000+0530)/"
    var takeDate: String = responsedate.componentsSeparatedByString("(")[1].componentsSeparatedByString(")")[0]
    var date: NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (CDouble(takeDate)! / 1000))
 
In `date` you will get the actual date. Further you can format it in "MM/dd/yyyy" format by using

    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    takeDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik There is problem with comma it says String(")",)[0] but still an error after the comma

Comment: I am not familier with swift , remove `/Date(` and `)/` from `/Date(1454956200000+0530)/` , after that your contine your work , it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code:

```
let date : NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1454956200000)
let tz : NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone(); //Default TimeZone. You can set any.
let seconds : Int = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(date);
var date = NSDate(timeInterval:Double(seconds), sinceDate: date)

let dateForm = NSDateFormatter();

let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale();

dateForm.locale = locale
dateForm.dateFormat = "MMM dd"; //the formate in which u want to convert.

let strStartTime = dateForm.stringFromDate(date);
```

Comment: How would you remove the plus part? cause I get that as a string and I cannot convert that to a double

Comment: You can split with + sign. With use of split functionality, you'll get array and use first index from that array.

Comment: @Max :- Please accept answer, if i could help you.